# SublimeText3 Ruby Debugger

Tags: debugging, sublimetext

I just set up the [SublimeText Ruby Debugger](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Ruby%20Debugger), attempting to run it with my Rails app, I get this error:

```
Connecting... 
Connection could not be made: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)
```

script/rails does exist

Any help in troubleshooting this one is GREATLY appreciated.

My environment:

```
$ sublime3 --version
Sublime Text Build 3059

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

$ which ruby
/home/merl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

$ gem list|grep byebug
byebug (2.5.0)

$ irb -r 'byebug'
2.0.0p247 :001 > 

$ uname -a
Linux ultra 3.5.0-45-generic #68~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 16:18:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.9

$ cd dev/cvef/essays/

$ ll script/

total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 merl merl 4096 Oct 11 21:11 .
drwxrwxr-x 15 merl merl 4096 Feb  4 16:14 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 merl merl  295 Oct 11 21:11 rails
```

sublime_debugger

Answer (score -1):

I just uploaded a new version that should handle that problem. thanks to a push request.

Shuky.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually… answer OP's question: what was the issue? How did you fix it? Can you provide an explanation, optionally with a link to the pull request you're talking about?